# Error with .jpeg in Georeferencer

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, error, jpg

QGIS error message when in Georeferencer:
.jpg is not a supported raster data source.
libjpeg: Bogus Huffman table definition

How do I fix this?
Tried different .jpeg and still doesn't work.
Previous fixes have included coding stuff which I don't understand, so haven't used.
Anyone have a plain English explaintion/fix?

The current released version of QGIS is 3.14.15.
On Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faced the same error in QGIS 3.14 on Win7.

I converted `.jpg` to `.png` in Paint. The converted `.png` opens in Georeferencer fine.

Probably [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181005/is-a-jpeg-with-a-bogus-huffman-table-recoverable) can help if converting isn't an option.

Comment: Thanks for that, will try that next time. :)